# Editing a CSS-defined item with HTML

Tags: html, css

I have defined a thing using css, like so

```
#box {
    background-color: white;
}
```

and then later call it using

```
<div id="box">
```

inside the div is where I get a new color. How do I change the color of the #box within the div?

Comment: Do you really mean `<div id="post">` and `#box`? If so, where exactly is the `box` id used?

Comment: Or do you want to change the color of `#box` that is inside of `#post`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `style`

```
<div id="box" style="background-color:#abcabc">
```

where #abcabc is your new color

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what you are asking, but from my understanding of your question:

```
#box {
background-color: white;
}
```

> and then later call it using

```
<div id="post">
```

The part `#box` says that the CSS should apply to something with the ID "box", but your actual div has the ID "post".  Try this:

```
<div id="box">
```

Alternatively you could use `#post` and `id="post"`.  The key is that they must match.

Comment: That was simply a typo on my part, I did mean to put id="box" but I still need help changing the background-color inside the div